# ¿Cómo ignorar todos los archivos de una carpeta en git pero manteniendo la carpeta?

Tags: git, gitignore

**Un poco de contexto**

Tengo un app en php bastante simple, puedes subir imágenes de tus productos. Por tanto tengo varias imágenes de prueba en mi carpeta pero al subir el proyecto al servidor usando git, no quiero que esas imágenes se suban.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**El problema**

Intente ignorar las imágenes de esta forma en mi .gitignore `sistema/images/fotos_articulos/*.jpg`

El problema es que al hacer el pull en mi servidor no crea la carpeta y eso me genera un error cuando trato de subir imágenes dentro del sistema, claro siempre puedo crearla manualmente por ftp

**Preguntas**

- ¿Cuál es la manera apropiada de ignorar solo el contenido de la carpeta?

Comment: Git no admite carpetas vacías en un repositorio. Basta que añadas a esa carpeta un fichero cualquiera que no termine en `.jpg`. Por ejemplo `no-borrar.txt`. Puede estar vacío, pero mejor si contiene un texto explicando por qué está ahí y no hay que borrarlo :-)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Estás ignorando correctamente las imágenes pero git no va a meter en el repositorio un directorio vacío.

Lo que puedes hacer es crear un .gitignore dentro del directorio y añadir las siguientes reglas:

```
*
!.gitignore
```

Es decir, que ignore todos los ficheros menos él mismo. Así la carpeta vaciá se añadirá al repositorio.

Comment: Gracias esta opción que me pareció la más simple y práctica, había hecho solo  *.jpg  pero con tu ejemplo está mucho mejor.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes crear dentro de la carpeta que contiene las imágenes un archivo llamado `.gitkeep` con el comando `touch .gitkeep` para que el directorio no se considere como vacío ya que no es posible hacerle `commit` a una carpeta vacía

Ahora regresas a la raíz del proyecto y en tu archivo `.gitignore` agregas lo siguiente

```
#para descartar todos los archivos
fotos_articulos/*

#para no ignorar la carpeta así como el archivo .gitkeep pero si los demás 
 archivos, es decir las imágenes
!fotos_articulos/.gitkeep
```

Answer (score 1):

Para mantener tus sub-directorios y evitar hacer un commit de su contenido, sera necesario incluir un archivo `.gitignore` en cada directorio con diferentes instrucciones.

NOTA: `.gitkeep` no es un archivo reconocido por git, y puedes utilizar el mismo .gitignore

1. En tu carpeta raiz `/` agrega un archivo .gitignore con lo siguente:

> ```
> # Ignora todo lo de la carpeta images, excepto el archivo fotos/.gitingnore
> images/*
> !images/fotos/.gitignore
> ```

2. En tu carpeta `/images` agrega un archivo .gitignore con lo siguente:

> ```
> # Omitir el archivo .gitingnore y la carpeta fotos
> !.gitignore
> !fotos
> ```

3. En tu carpeta `/images/fotos` agrega un archivo .gitignore con lo siguente:

> ```
> # Ignora todo el contenido excepto el archivo .gitingnore
> *
> !.gitignore
> ```

Aunque parezca redudante `!images/fotos/.gitignore` del paso 1 y `!.gitignore` del paso 3 es necesario debido a que se hace una exclusion del .gitignore global